# Firebase: How to generate confirmation code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do some email verification stuff inside my app, using the methods `sendEmailVerification` and `applyActionCode`. However, after creating an account using my email address, and executing sendEmailVerification: I have received a message containing only confirmation link but without any validation code.

So how is it possible to generate and receive confirmation code using firebase?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you getting the email validation link? If you click it does it open the default action code page with the confirmation that your email was verified? That is the expected behavior. You can update the landing page in the firebase console to a custom page that you own and then parse the code yourself from the url to verify the code on your own. We are currently working on the documentation for building a custom action code handler. So stay tuned.

Comment: @bojeil Yes I'm getting the email confirmation link, that's what I only get <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/yci00xrrj/firebasevalidation.png"> when I click on it.

Comment: This is the intended behavior. It means that the email was verified. The code and the action mode are passed in the url and the code is verified via applyActionCode for you in the default landing page. Documentation will be updated in the coming weeks with instructions how to build your own custom email verification, password reset, etc landing page.

Comment: @bojeil Hmm .. got it. The 'oobCode' parameter is what I need. Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'oobCode' parameter inside the confirmation link is what needed in this case.